# Use the sequence of partial sums to show that the given series is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

**Edit**: When I first wrote this question, I accidentally wrote "i=0" instead of k=1.  Sorry about that! Where i, of course, is imaginary.

The series is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{k+2i} - \frac{1}{k+1+2i}\right]$$
Sorry if this is a stupid question but both my book and my professor explained this really poorly. I think I can figure it out if someone can show me how to find a and z in order to use the equation for finding the sum, $\frac{a}{1-z}$.
Thanks!

Comment: Use the hint in the question. Write down the first, second and third partial sums and see the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial sum $S_n$ is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S_n &=& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left[ \frac{1}{k+2i} - \frac{1}{k+1+2i} \right] \\
&=& \left[ \frac{1}{1+2i} - \frac{1}{2+2i} \right]
 + \left[ \frac{1}{2+2i} - \frac{1}{3+2i} \right]
 + ...
 + \left[ \frac{1}{n+2i} - \frac{1}{n+1+2i} \right] \\
&=& \frac{1}{1+2i} - \frac{1}{n+1+2i} \\
&=& \frac{n}{n(1+2i) - (3-4i)} \\
&=& \frac{\frac{1}{1+2i}}{1 - \frac{3-4i}{n(1+2i)}} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

As $n$ tends to infinity, the sum is

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{1+2i}}{1 - \frac{3-4i}{n(1+2i)}} \\
&=& \frac{\frac{1}{1+2i}}{1 - 0}\\
&=& \frac{1}{1+2i}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So you have $a = 1$ and $z = -2i$.

Comment: Notice that this is *not* a telescoping series - there is *no* cancellation. Also notice that the two terms, when combined, are $\dfrac{1}{(k+2i)(k+2i+1)}$ which shows convergence.

Comment: @martycohen, I initially expanded the series expecting a telescoping series but I was pleasantly surprised to find this series instead.

Comment: Actually, I prefer a telescoping series.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice until I looked at your answer that I screwed up writing the question - it should be k=1 to infinity, not i=0. Could you please tell me how you would approach it with that?

Comment: @RachelMac, I just updated my answer. Does the approach make sense?

Comment: The approach makes sense (thank you so much for doing that).  How do you go from the second to last step to the last step, though?  Specifically, the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Prove that the sequence of partial sums is $S_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i}}{k+i}$